# Load and then append on AJAX Success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using AJAX to send inputted data to the database which I've managed to achieve. Where I'm struggling is on the success parameter. I'm trying to load and then append a PHP file once the initial AJAX call is successfully completed.

```
var data = $("#form_write_post").serializeArray()

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $("#form_write_post").attr("action"),
    data: data,
    async: false,
    success: $.get("test.php", function(data) {
        $('ul.timeline').append(data);
    });
});
```

I managed to append JavaScript data but I need to be able to get other data from the database.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Comment: Create function for getting data from `test.php` and on first ajax success call it:
function refreshData() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'test.php',
    success: function(data) {
        $('ul.timeline').append(data);
    };
});
}

and in saving ajax success call it:
success: function(data) {
        refreshData();
    };

Answer (score 2):

remove `$.get(){}` in success

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test.php', //if ur action is test.php
    data: data,
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('ul.timeline').append(data);
    });
});
```